# Use JQuery Validate plugin on a function

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I have this function where I want to use the JQuery validation plugin but I cant get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var validateForm = function()
{
    $('#mainForm').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            firstName: "Enter car year",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('valid form submitted');
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }
    }) 

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What error do you get in browser console if any?

Comment: I didn't get any error but it doesn't validate. I think I figured it out. I separated it from the function and called $('#mainForm').validate(); on the function instead

Comment: Yes that's the right way to do it. You just need to declare the validate on the form and it starts working automatically.

Comment: Cool. I'm still new to the JQuery plugin. I like it a lot. Thanks!!